# understand the implementation of substrate-api-sidecar

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-api-sidecar

I want to know the implementation of `http://127.0.0.1:8080/blocks/head` endpoint from (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar)

I found some interface here https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/rpc-augment/src/augment/jsonrpc.ts#L85
and some implementation https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/api-derive/src/chain/getHeader.ts

but this function doesn't makes sense to me. lack of RxJS understanding I guess. can anyone give me a good direction? I want to see the actual implementation of that particular API...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the entry to the API is [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/master/src/controllers/blocks/BlocksController.ts). Then, the actual logic of it is [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/master/src/services/blocks/BlocksService.ts).